# change color current link page angular & css

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to amend my projetc which has been built so that there is a sub menu which appears on every page but is coded only once.
I want to be able to add a highlight to the link for the page you are currently viewing, but I have to do this all in one html snippet
The list renders fine, except that I can't get the current page to highlight.
I have read some other posts about adding 'current link' formatting in a separate file but, unfortunately, I have to include all the code in this snippet.I have to do it by using HTML, CSS and angular and i'm new in learning angular

Given that, is what I am trying to achieve possible and if yes how can i make it work?

```css
body {
  font-family: Source Sans Pro;
}

ul {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  float: left;
  width: 6em;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.2em 0.6em;
  border-right: 1px solid white;

}

#navbar li a.current {
  background-color: #FFF;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

#bl {
  background-color: #5a5a5a;
  color: yellow;
}

#or {
  background-color: #5a5a5a;
  color: yellow;
}

#gr {
  background-color: #5a5a5a;
  color: yellow;
}

#bl:hover, #or:hover, #gr:hover {
  background-color: #ff6900;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<body ng-app="watch"> 
  <div ng-controller="control"> 
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" ng-click = "person()" id="bl">Person</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" ng-click = "product()" id="or">Product</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" ng-click = "place()" id="gr">Place</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

my controller look like this

```js
'use strict';
var mymodule = angular.module("watch", []);

mymodule.controller("control",function($scope) {
    $scope.jsonerator = true;
    $scope.jsonerator2 = false;
 $scope.jsonerator3 = false;
 
 
    $scope.person = function() {
        $scope.jsonerator = true;
        $scope.jsonerator2 = false;
  $scope.jsonerator3 = false;
  
   }
 
 
  $scope.product = function() {
        $scope.jsonerator = false;
        $scope.jsonerator2 = true;
  $scope.jsonerator3 = false;
  
  }
 
 
  $scope.place = function() {
        $scope.jsonerator = false;
        $scope.jsonerator2 = false;
  $scope.jsonerator3 = true;
     }
};
```

and this is my menu on jsfiddle:[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ekw2s6az/)

Thanks

Comment: May we see your controller's JavaScript?

Comment: sorry i just added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I suggest, in addition to changing your CSS IDs to classes (and probably eliminating the IDs from your a tags). You may also find that you don't need as much code by using [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass); it will apply the class when the boolean statement after the colon is true. In this case, we're using your jsonerator $scope variables.

```
<li><a href="#" ng-click = "person()" id="bl" ng-class="{bl: jsonerator}">Person</a></li>
<li><a href="#" ng-click = "product()" id="or" ng-class="{or: jsonerator2}">Product</a></li>
<li><a href="#" ng-click = "place()" id="gr" ng-class="{gr: jsonerator3}">Place</a></li>
```